# Make mouse cursor visible

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

Whenever the keyboard is used in a web page, the mouse cursor disappears until the user moves the mouse again. Is there a way to programmatically make it visible again from a page's javascript? Changing the cursor CSS has no impact.

Given that this is a system-wide phenomenon (at least on OSX), I'm guessing that the answer is no, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: This is handled by OSX, not the browser. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71661/how-do-i-disable-hiding-of-the-mouse-pointer-while-typing-text.

Comment: Cool, thanks. In my circumstance, I'm changing the cursor to a png when the user uses a specific keyboard shortcut, so I'm going to try to inject that same png into the page at the cursor location then remove it on mouse-move. Hopefully it'll look okay.